# the app crashes with adding URL to MainActivity.kt

Tags: php, android, kotlin, android-studio, url

I work with kotlin and I want to show alert after checking the url response
My codes in MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.test1

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.net.URL


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        val username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etUserName);
        val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etPassword);
        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button);


        var url = URL("https://www.sepehrfarm.ir/app/read.php?username=host&password=1111").readText();
            if(url == "okay"){
                        btn.setOnClickListener {
                            val mAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                            mAlertDialog.setTitle("Show Dialog");
                            mAlertDialog.setMessage("Login successful");
                            mAlertDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog: DialogInterface, id: Int ->
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    this@MainActivity,
                                    "OK",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                            mAlertDialog.show()
                        }
            }
            else{
                btn.setOnClickListener {
                    val mAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                    mAlertDialog.setTitle("Show Dialog");
                    mAlertDialog.setMessage("Login failed");
                    mAlertDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
               

     mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog: DialogInterface, id:Int ->
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@MainActivity,
                            "OK",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                    mAlertDialog.show()
                }
            }

    }
    }
```

during var url = URL("https://www.sepehrfarm.ir/app/read.php?username=host&password=1111").readText() is in the program, the app does not work and when I comment this line the app runs properly
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing the network operation on the main thread. If you are doing network operations on the main thread. this will cause the application to hang and get an ANR error.

In your code, this line makes a network request.

```
var url = URL("https://www.sepehrfarm.ir/app/read.php?username=host&password=1111").readText();
```

You should do this on a background thread.
To solve this problem, you can use **Coroutines** or **RX**.

Below is an example of working with coroutines.

```
dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.1"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"
    }
```

Changing the code in onCreate:

```
val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            // Start a coroutine to perform the network request on a background thread
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val url = URL("https://www.sepehrfarm.ir/app/read.php?username=host&password=1111").readText()
               // val response = url.component1()

                // Perform UI updates on the main thread
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    if (url == "okay") {
                        showAlertDialog("Login successful")
                    } else {
                        showAlertDialog("Login failed")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I took out the method for showing the dialog separately.

```
private fun showAlertDialog(message: String) {
        val mAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            .setTitle("Show Dialog")
            .setMessage(message)
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog: DialogInterface, id: Int ->
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            .create()
        mAlertDialog.show()
    }
```

You can learn more about coroutines at this [link](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines).